# Unable to Deserialize Json downloaded from a URL

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I am trying to ***deserialize*** the JSON downloaded from the following site downloaded as *RawData*

[Json from the Site](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/everypolitician/everypolitician-data@a83a045d550b06c48138534e349b7ef155ac110a/data/Pakistan/Assembly/ep-popolo-v1.0.json)

but following error is being thrown

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type '' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

I tried using following methods

```
Root[] roots= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root[]>(jsonString);
```

and

```
var roots = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(jsonString);
```

I used following class

```
public class Root
{
    public List<object> posts { get; set; }
    public List<Person> persons { get; set; }
    public List<Organization> organizations { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public List<Membership> memberships { get; set; }
    public List<Event> events { get; set; }
    public List<Area> areas { get; set; }
}
```

Following is the example JSON

```js
"posts": [

  ],
  "persons": [
    {
      "birth_date": "1957-08-09",
      "contact_details": [
        {
          "type": "email",
          "value": "hariomsingh.rathore@sansad.nic.in"
        }
      ],
      "email": "hariomsingh.rathore@sansad.nic.in",
      "gender": "male",
      "id": "0094ff14-ff6c-440a-96fc-f0bd68068569",
      "identifiers": [
        {
          "identifier": "4655",
          "scheme": "everypolitician_legacy"
        },
        {
          "identifier": "hariomsinghrathore",
          "scheme": "prsindia"
        },
        {
          "identifier": "Q16897877",
          "scheme": "wikidata"
        }
      ],
      "image": "http://164.100.47.132/mpimage/photo/4655.jpg",
      "images": [
        {
          "url": "http://164.100.47.132/mpimage/photo/4655.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        {
          "note": "Wikipedia (en)",
          "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hariom_Singh_Rathore"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Yavatmal-Washim",
      "other_names": [
        {
          "lang": "en",
          "name": "Yavatmal-Washim Lok Sabha constituency",
          "note": "multilingual"
        },
        {
          "lang": "hi",
          "name": "à¤¯à¤µà¤¤à¤®à¤¾à¤²-à¤µà¤¾à¤¶à¤¿à¤® à¤²à¥‹à¤• à¤¸à¤­à¤¾ à¤¨à¤¿à¤°à¥à¤µà¤¾à¤šà¤¨ à¤•à¥à¤·à¥‡à¤¤à¥à¤°",
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> {
  "posts": [

  ],
  "persons": [
    {
      "birth_date": "1957-08-09",
      "contact_details": [
        {
          "type": "email",
          "value": "hariomsingh.rathore@sansad.nic.in"
        }
      ],
      "email": "hariomsingh.rathore@sansad.nic.in",
      "gender": "male",
      "id": "0094ff14-ff6c-440a-96fc-f0bd68068569",
      "identifiers": [
        {
          "identifier": "4655",
          "scheme": "everypolitician_legacy"
        },
        {
          "identifier": "hariomsinghrathore",
          "scheme": "prsindia"
        },
        {
          "identifier": "Q16897877",
          "scheme": "wikidata"
        }
      ],
      "image": "http://164.100.47.132/mpimage/photo/4655.jpg",
      "images": [
        {
          "url": "http://164.100.47.132/mpimage/photo/4655.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        {
          "note": "Wikipedia (en)",
          "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hariom_Singh_Rathore"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Rathore, Shri Hariom Singh",
      "other_names": [
        {
          "lang": "en",
          "name": "Hariom Singh Rathore",
          "note": "multilingual"
        },
        {
          "lang": "gu",
          "name": "àª¹àª°àª¿àª“àª® àª¸àª¿àª‚àª¹ àª°àª¾àª à«Œàª¡àª¼",
          "note": "multilingual"
        }
        
      ]
    },
    {
      "birth_date": "1975-09-10",
      "contact_details": [
        {
          "type": "email",
          "value": "ravneetbittu@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      "email": "ravneetbittu@gmail.com",
      "family_name": "Singh",
      "gender": "male",
      "id": "01727319-7f2b-465b-825c-1d7a94a54f70",
      "identifiers": [
        {
          "identifier": "4429",
          "scheme": "everypolitician_legacy"
        },
        {
          "identifier": "ravneetsingh",
          "scheme": "prsindia"
        },
        
      ],
      "image": "http://164.100.47.132/mpimage/photo/4429.jpg",
      "images": [
        {
          "url": "http://164.100.47.132/mpimage/photo/4429.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        {
          "note": "Wikipedia (en)",
          "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravneet_Singh_Bittu"
        },
        {
          "note": "Wikipedia (pa)",
          "url": "https://pa.wikipedia.org/wiki/à¨°à¨µà¨¨à©€à¨¤_à¨¸à¨¿à©°à¨˜"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Singh, Shri Ravneet",
      "other_names": [
          "note": "multilingual"
        },
        {
          "lang": "mr",
          "name": "à¤¯à¤µà¤¤à¤®à¤¾à¤³-à¤µà¤¾à¤¶à¤¿à¤® (à¤²à¥‹à¤•à¤¸à¤­à¤¾ à¤®à¤¤à¤¦à¤¾à¤°à¤¸à¤‚à¤˜)",
          "note": "multilingual"
        },
        {
          "lang": "ta",
        {
          "lang": "en",
          "name": "Ravneet Singh",
          "note": "multilingual"
        },
        
        {
          "lang": "te",
          "name": "à°°à°µà°¨à±€à°¤à± à°¸à°¿à°‚à°—à± à°¬à°¿à°Ÿà±à°Ÿà±‚",
          "note": "multilingual"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "birth_date": "1958-09-07",
      "contact_details": [
        {
          "type": "email",
          "value": "bhairon.prasad@sansad.nic.in"
        }
      ],
      "email": "bhairon.prasad@sansad.nic.in",
      "family_name": "Mishra",
      "gender": "male",
      "id": "02670d6a-6b60-4e7b-b0cd-b4fc7d6c3bca",
      "identifiers": [
        {
          "identifier": "4626",
          "scheme": "everypolitician_legacy"
        },
        
        {
          "identifier": "Q16902096",
          "scheme": "wikidata"
        }
      ],
      "image": "http://164.100.47.132/mpimage/photo/4626.jpg",
      "images": [
        {
          "url": "http://164.100.47.132/mpimage/photo/4626.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        {
          "note": "Wikipedia (en)",
          "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhairon_Prasad_Mishra"
        },
        {
          "note": "Wikipedia (hi)",
          "url": "https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/à¤­à¥ˆà¤°à¥‹à¤‚_à¤ªà¥à¤°à¤¸à¤¾à¤¦_à¤®à¤¿à¤¶à¥à¤°"
        }
      ],
          "name": "à®¯à®µà®¤à¯à®®à®¾à®³à¯-à®µà®¾à®šà®¿à®®à¯ à®®à®•à¯à®•à®³à®µà¯ˆà®¤à¯ à®¤à¯Šà®•à¯à®¤à®¿",
          "note": "multilingual"
        }
      ],
      "type": "constituency"
    },
    {
      "id": "zahirabad",
      "identifiers": [
        {
          "identifier": "Q8064692",
          "scheme": "wikidata"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Zahirabad",
      "other_names": [
        {
          "lang": "en",
          "name": "Zahirabad Lok Sabha constituency",
          "note": "multilingual"
        },
        {
          "lang": "hi",
          "name": "à¤œà¤¼à¤¹à¥€à¤°à¤¾à¤¬à¤¾à¤¦ à¤²à¥‹à¤• à¤¸à¤­à¤¾ à¤¨à¤¿à¤°à¥à¤µà¤¾à¤šà¤¨ à¤•à¥à¤·à¥‡à¤¤à¥à¤° à¤¸à¤®à¥à¤ªà¤¾à¤¦à¤¨",
          "note": "multilingual"
        },
        {
          "lang": "mr",
          "name": "à¤à¤¹à¥€à¤°à¤¾à¤¬à¤¾à¤¦ (à¤²à¥‹à¤•à¤¸à¤­à¤¾ à¤®à¤¤à¤¦à¤¾à¤°à¤¸à¤‚à¤˜)",
          "note": "multilingual"
        },
        {
          "lang": "ta",
          "name": "à®œà®¹à¯€à®°à®¾à®ªà®¾à®¤à¯",
          "note": "multilingual"
        },
        {
          "lang": "te",
          "name": "à°œà°¹à±€à°°à°¾à°¬à°¾à°¦à± à°²à±‹à°•à°¸à°­ à°¨à°¿à°¯à±‹à°œà°•à°µà°°à±à°—à°‚",
          "note": "multilingual"
        }
      ],
      "type": "constituency"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can any one please help me in doing that. Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you're using.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the json in your question that will cause the issue you are seeing. No one helping you should have to download a file from an unknown site to provide you help with your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is not an array of roots.  The json is a single object with multiple nested objects inside a single root.

```
{
 "posts": [
  ],
 "persons": [
  { "birth_date":
}
```

Since it's not returning an array of objects, you need to deserialize to a singular root.

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```